# Angular 7 : setTimeout method not work in select tag

Tags: angular

I want to use `setTimeout()` method in select tag and when I change any option then i want to set other default selected value of select options  in `setTimeout` method.

I can do it using function also but i don't want to write function in `component` file .

It should be workable like javascript,

```
<button onclick="setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000))">Try it</button>
```

**Html File**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Type</label>
<select 
    [name]="contact.contactMethod" 
    [id]="contact.contactMethod" 
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="contact.contactMethod">
    (change)="setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 500)" // here alert not working, i want to assign other select option value here
    <option *ngFor="let method of contactMethodsArray" [value]="method.id">{{ method.label }}</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible for alert here ? Can someone please help me for these scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function on change event of select then,you can do it by following way

demo.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Type</label>
<select 
    [name]="contact.contactMethod" 
    [id]="contact.contactMethod" 
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="contact.contactMethod">
    onchange="setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 5000)"
    <option *ngFor="let method of contactMethodsArray" [value]="method.id">{{ method.label }}</option>
</select>
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks @sandy I have did mistake in event `(change)` it would be `onchange`

Answer (score 1):

The statement [context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#statement-context) is the component class but within the componet there is no function named `setTimeout` so it wont work as you expected, check your console there you can see some error.

Create a simple function within component which calls the `setTimeout` and use it within templatw.

**Template :**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Type</label>
<select 
    [name]="contact.contactMethod" 
    [id]="contact.contactMethod" 
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="contact.contactMethod">
    (change)="someFunction()" 
    <option *ngFor="let method of contactMethodsArray" [value]="method.id">{{ method.label }}</option>
```

**Component :**

```
someFunction():void {
   setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 500);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tc9vzh)

---

ALternately you can use native `onchange`(not recommended) method as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Type</label>
<select 
    [name]="contact.contactMethod" 
    [id]="contact.contactMethod" 
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="contact.contactMethod">
    onchange="setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 500)" 
    <option *ngFor="let method of contactMethodsArray" [value]="method.id">{{ method.label }}</option>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztvhyn)

Comment: Hi @Pranav i have update my question please check i want expected as a javascript

Comment: @BhagwatTupe :  then you can rely on `onchange="setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 500)"`

Comment: Hi i have also try `onchange="setTimeout('alert(\'Hello!\')', 500)"` these but didn't work

Comment: so no need to defined function in component

Comment: @BhagwatTupe :  `onchange` works on global context since setTimeout is in global context it will work..... _cons: you can't access component function directly here_